# BMW E70 CCC DVD and CD player supported formats

Tags: bmw

Please help me to find which formats support DVD reader and CD reader of BMW X5 E70 3.0d 2008 with CCC multimedia system.

Comment: Model etc of the cd unit?

Comment: @SolarMike can you tell how to find out the model of my dvd/cd unit?

Comment: Take it out and look?

Comment: what do you mean by "format"s?  dvd players are standardized to accept dvds or cds.  If you are wondering about playback of personal files, the video is in mpeg-2 format.

Answer (score 1):

**Audio:**

- Audio CD (CD-DA)
- MP3
- WMA
- OGG
- AAC

**Video:**

- Video DVD (Region locked to your vehicle's region)
- Video CD (VCD)
- Super Video CD (SVCD)
- MPEG1
- MPEG2
- MPEG4
- DivX

**Images:**

- JPEG